# sum numbers in textarea with jQuery

Tags: jquery

If I have a text area with text and some numbers, like

```
<textarea id="ta">some text <cars (5)> and more text <bikes (10)> blah...</a>
```

How can I get a sum of all numbers in that textarea on load with jQuery (n = 5 + 10)?

Comment: are the numbers always surrounded by parenthesis?

Comment: The truth is: You cannot perform any mathematical operation with jQuery (without plugins)! ;o) Seriously: This is JavaScript problem, not a jQuery problem. What is the generic form of the text? Can there be other numbers than those in the "tags"?

Comment: @Kyle Yes, and I can get it out with regex (if it were just one field): $(#myField).match(/\(([0-9]+)\)/)[1];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var sum = 0;
var numbers = $("#ta").text().match(/\d+/g);

if (numbers)
{
    $.each(numbers, function() {
        sum += parseInt(this);
    });
}
```

You may need to modify the regex if all numbers shouldn't be included.

Edit: If you only want numbers wrapped in parens, you could use the following:

```
var sum = 0;
var regex = /\((\d+)\)/g;
var text = $("#ta").text();

while (match = regex.exec(text))
{
    sum += parseInt(match[1]);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best...

http://jsfiddle.net/WxUwv/